# Can't understand a thing about emissivity concept

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation

I can't understand something about emissivity. Emissivity is defined as the ratio of the radiant energy of an object,  to radiant energy of blackbody at a temperature $T$. So, The vegetation has approximate emissivity of $0.99$ and concrete smaller than this like $0.95$. But in thermal images vegetation appears darker than concrete. If its emittance is much more; so why is it dark? If the vegetation emits more energy why does it look dark in thermal imagery?

Comment: Hmmm... thermal imaging should just use the infrared spectrum though, which muddles things.

Comment: this landsat thermal band 10.5 - 12.5 micrometers interval band 6 --> http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/browse/tm/25/39/1985/LT50250391985280XXX01_TIR.jpg and this is the true color --> http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/browse/tm/25/39/1985/LT50250391985280XXX01_REFL.jpg you see vegetation is dark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply having a higher thermal emissivity does not mean an object will emit more energy than another. Consider, if you will, walking barefoot outside in the summer. If you walk on concrete or the road, you'll find yourself jumping around like a ballet dancer. But if you walk on vegetation (leaves, grass, your neighbour's flower garden, etc.), you'll probably find it is a lot cooler. This indicates a main reason (there are a couple others, but I'm giving room for others to post answers as well) for why vegetation looks darker on thermal images than concrete; it *is* cooler. Since vegetation is significantly cooler (usually) than things like roads, it can have a higher emissivity but still emit less thermal radiation.

Comment: The thermal images that i put in first comment are the images where emissvity is considered 1 for whole scene. i know the Planck's radiation formula (sorry for my poor latex knowledge) describes the radiation emitted by a blackbody at a temperature T. So you say that the temperature of grass is less than the temperature of concrete in day time. So concrete emitts more thermal infrared radiation. But isn't a good absorber also a good emitter according to Kirchhoff's law? So vegetation absorbs solar radiation better than concrete.

Comment: true, but vegetation also does stuff with solar radiation like photosynthesis. Thermal conductance also plays into it

Comment: Jim really thanks alot for answering my questions. Maybe they are dumb questions. But i really want to figure out what is going on in thermal spectrum. One more? :) Water also have high emissivity and appears dark too. so it has less thermal conductance. Healty vegetation contains water. So the water effects the thermal conductance of vegetation?

Comment: "has less thermal conductance". Sorry, perhaps I was unclear. The transportation of thermal energy plays into it. Water appears dark because it can use convection to cycle the heat to lower depths and generally disperse it "well". Similarly, vegetation has ways of transporting thermal energy. Concrete and asphalt, on the other hand, tends to have the heat remain at the surface, thus it heats up more from the same incident solar radiation.

Comment: Oh i got it now. The material properties of objects are also important about their thermal radiation. Sorry i bothered you with my silly questions. But iam not a physicist or engineer. Just a high school student that loves physics :) Thanks alot :) !!!

Comment: Sorry for the spam. My last wish :). Then i will be disapeared forever before you vaporise me for asking too many questions :) I googled alot but couldnt find. Is there any document or something that explain this with mathematics or figures?

Comment: I can't name any off hand. I'm sure there are, but most physicists grow into understanding this sort of phenomenon.